# The remote endpoint could not be called, or the response it returned was invalid. (alexa, aws)

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I'm currently getting into developing alexa-skills. This is in fact the 1st time I'm trying this and I kinda works out good so far. However, I stumbled upon a problem which seems to be wide-spreaded but I couldn't find an answer how to solve it.

First things first:
I started this skill by following [a tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zt9WdE5kR6g). It might be that this tutorial is outdated and therefore this error appears.

I created a skill from the scratch and it works to the part where the `LaunchRequest` is invoked:

[image]

As you can see, I get my response as expected. (works on the test-environment as well as on alexa itself). Now, when try to call an `IntentRequest`, I just get the error-message:

> The remote endpoint could not be called, or the response it returned was invalid.

[image]

As I can tell from the picture / request, the correct intent-request is called (in my case `getSubscriberCount` ) - And this is the point where I have no idea anymore on how to resolve this problem.

To keep things short, this here is the JS-part for the Intent:

case "IntentRequest":
        // Intent Request
        console.log(`INTENT REQUEST`)

```
    switch(event.request.intent.name) {
        case "GetSubscriberCount":
            var endpoint = "my url"
            var body = ""
            https.get(endpoint, (response) => {
                response.on('data', (chunk) => { body += chunk })
    response.on('end', () => {
        var data = JSON.parse(body)
        var subscriberCount = data.items[0].statistics.subscriberCount
        context.succeed(
        generateResponse(
            buildSpeechletResponse(`Du hast momentan ${subscriberCount} Abonnenten`, true),
            {}
        )
    )
```

And this is causing my problems. To test what exactly is wrong, I tried the following:

- Called the endpoint in my browser --> Correct output
- Adjusted the "response" to the minimum to see if that works --> didn't work
- Checked several sources related to this error --> didn't help either

I saw some approaches to get rid of this, since this seems to be a common issue, but I got lost. [Someone](https://github.com/nightscout/cgm-remote-monitor/issues/2885#issuecomment-345919106) mentioned an environment variable, which I couldn't put my hands on. [Another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40834981/alexa-skill-arn-the-remote-endpoint-could-not-be-called-or-the-response-it-re) suggested to run the JSON request manually, which I tried, but leading to the same error.

Hopefully you can help me out here.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you AWS lambda, it might be because you didn't create your response right or your AWS lambda function had a error.