# Alexa Not able to invoke custom skills

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I have developed a customer skills API in Java. I hosted the service as secure service in Azure.

I am trying to now configure amazon alexa to call the service from intent. I am able to test the service from the "test" tab in new skill configuration page. 
During testing, I am able to receive the proper response for the utterance.
However when I tried using the Amazon Echo device, its not calling the service. When I talk to dot, it gives me a response "there is a problem with request skills response". What might be the issue?

Comment: You need to debug your Java implementation - see if it is crashing out or what it is returning.

Answer (score 0):

This error message is very broad and may imply a lot of different issues. I was getting this error and in my case it was a timeout issue. How long does Azure take to respond? The timeout doesn't seem to be properly documented, see my original question here: [Troubleshooting Amazon's Alexa Skill Kit (ASK) Lambda interaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38887061/troubleshooting-amazons-alexa-skill-kit-ask-lambda-interaction)

Answer (score 0):

it said 'problem with ...skill response' so there must have been one. You can check what the HTTP error code was from your alexa app-in home you have some history of interactions. Responses like 301, 404, 405, 50x are likely to be seen ;)

If that is not enough-maybe you could start your service with more verbose logging?